# How to configure tomcat to rollover catalina.log files

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat6, catalina

I'm trying to configure my tomcat to rollover log files once a size limit is reached. I'm running tomcat as a windows service and am redirecting all my stdout to catalina.log. This is how I configured by logging.properties to set a size limit. But it is not working.

logging.properties

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = e:/apache-tomcat/logs/server_111-1001
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.limit = 100000 # size 100kb 
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.count = 5


2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = e:/apache-tomcat/logs/server_111-1001
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = e:/apache-tomcat/logs/server_111-1001
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = e:/apache-tomcat/logs/server_111-1001
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.level=FINE
```

But 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.limit = 100000 doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Why would you even write anything to the stdout in a web application?! This is going to kill your performance if you get any kind of load to talk of. Can't you use log4j or some other logging library?

Comment: Because, when running tomcat as a service, the console messages are going directly to stdout.log.

Comment: Is there anyway I can rotate stdout.log atlease

Comment: Where are those console messages coming from? Do you have system.out.println all over your web app?

Comment: Yes, the developers did a very bad job at this!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Tomcat JULI logging to roll log files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136300/how-to-configure-tomcat-juli-logging-to-roll-log-files)

Answer (score 13):

`org.apache.juli.FileHandler` does not support rotation based on file size and does not have the `limit` and `count` properties you are trying to set ([see docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html)). Instead, you can use the standard Java java.util.logging.FileHandler which supports size-based rotation. You should change the following lines in your configuration:

```
handlers = 1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

Also note that Java `FileHandler` is configured slightly differently than Tomcat `FileHandler`

```
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINEST
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = <your log dir>/catalina%g.log
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 100000
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 5
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

However, I'm not sure that redirecting standard out to the file written by the logger will work well and help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Official Tomcat 7 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html) :

---

> *public class FileHandler extends java.util.logging.Handler*
>
> Implementation of Handler that appends log messages to a file named
>   {prefix}{date}{suffix} in a configured directory.
>
> The following configuration properties are available:
>
> - directory - The directory where to create the log file. If the path is not absolute, it is relative to the current working directory
>     of the application. The Apache Tomcat configuration files usually
>     specify an absolute path for this property, ${catalina.base}/logs
>     Default value: logs
> - rotatable - If true, the log file will be rotated on the first write past midnight and the filename will be {prefix}{date}{suffix},
>     where date is yyyy-MM-dd. If false, the file will not be rotated and
>     the filename will be {prefix}{suffix}. Default value: true
> - prefix - The leading part of the log file name. Default value: juli.
> - suffix - The trailing part of the log file name. Default value: .log
> - bufferSize - Configures buffering. The value of 0 uses system default buffering (typically an 8K buffer will be used). A value of <0
>     forces a writer flush upon each log write. A value >0 uses a
>     BufferedOutputStream with the defined value but note that the system
>     default buffering will also be applied. Default value: -1
> - encoding - Character set used by the log file. Default value: empty string, which means to use the system default character set.
> - level - The level threshold for this Handler. See the java.util.logging.Level class for the possible levels. Default value:
>     ALL
> - filter - The java.util.logging.Filter implementation class name for this Handler. Default value: unset
> - formatter - The java.util.logging.Formatter implementation class name for this Handler. Default value:
>     java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter