# Tomcat9 - Limit Size or File Rotation of STDOUT and STDERR

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9, catalina

I am using Tomcat 9 to run application in Window 10 (Run as window service).

I would like to confirm how should I avoid the STDOUT or STDERR log file to be too big by any of two approach below:

1. Create new STDOUT or STDERR log when size hit 1GB size
2. Create new STDOUT or STDERR log daily

Is there any way to achieve on any approach above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure tomcat to rollover catalina.log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220189/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-rollover-catalina-log-files)

Comment: Hi kolossus, As I understand the JULI is not handle for STDOUT and STDERR. For other tomcat log is OK. Only STDOUT and STDERR got problem