# Geoserver randomly drops logs file

Tags: tomcat, logging, geoserver

Geoserver drops continuously a "logs" file at random. The logs file contains 'juli.xxxx-xx-xx.log' files. We don't make use of them but we can't get rid of it, don't know how to disable this ghost logging. It pops up in the root and even in configuration files. Anybody familiar with this problem?

How can I stop this 'logs file' popping up issue?

Comment: which operating system? how did you deploy GeoServer? does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136300/how-to-configure-tomcat-juli-logging-to-roll-log-files help?

Comment: linux rhel8. deploy jenkins buildserver, bitbucket script.
logging.properties configuration settings are changed to /var/log/tomcat/ due to business policy.